# Structure cannot be indexed because it has no default property

Tags: vb.net, properties, structure, default

I am getting the error message "Structure cannot be indexed because it has no default property". can anyone please show me what I'm doing wrong?

```
Public Structure Length8FixedString
    <VBFixedString(8)> Public myFixedString As String '8 is the STRING length.
End Structure


Public Structure ExampleStructure2
    <VBFixedArray(7)> Public myArray As Length8FixedString 
End Structure

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim V As New ExampleStructure2
        V.myArray(1) = "TIM" 'ERROR: Structure cannot be indexed because it has no default property
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared myArray as type FixedLengthString instead of as an array of FixedLengthString:

```
Public Structure ExampleStructure2
    <VBFixedArray(7)> Public myArray As Length8FixedString()
End Structure
```

Not sure if this is what you want because this exposes more problems.  An explanation of what you're trying to achieve will help if this isn't the answer.